# HX711 and 50kg load cell - possible update speed / dynamic load

Tags: load-cell

I bought [this 50kg load cell](https://www.berrybase.de/en/Pixelpdfdata/Articlepdf/id/2101/onumber/HWS-50) and an hx711 which I want to connect to my raspberry pi zero.

I'm wondering how accurate they are if I load them with a dynamic weight.
To take a simple analogy: could I measure say the force/torque on a bicycle pedal, rotating around 60 rpm with dynamic force, with 10 Hz and an accuracy of <5% (for the bicycle say 4 pounds or 2 kg) ?

Comment: How will you attach the load cell to something that is rotating? 
How fast can the hx711 sample? What is its samples per second?
Regarding accuracy... probably with calibration would be my guess

Comment: In this example, I could attach the load cell on top of the pedal, the electronics on the bottom of the pedal. Simplified, the pedal would move around the crank, but would not rotate.


The HX711 can run at either 10Hz or 80Hz update rate.
Question is: can I reliably sample at this frequency or is there another limit?
At least my bathroom or kitchen scale seems to take a few seconds, and I wonder why that is.

Comment: why are you asking and not testing?

Comment: @Holger 
The scales taking a long time is likely due to heavy filtering to get very accurate measurement. Hard to say how necessary it is without having collected data of the sensor in question first. We can't help any further without you collecting some data.

Comment: @jsotola: I'm asking because I think it's always great to learn from the mistakes of other people. I'm a novice in this topic, and if there is any obvious reason why it might not work, it's good to know before spending hours. As noone pointed out any obvious roadblock, I guess it's time to test and collect some data. :-)

Comment: couple of things come to mind ... 50 kg load cell is only adequate for a bicycle rider that weighs less than 50 kg ... the load cell may oscillate a lot before settling .... you can do a rough test of the oscillation by putting a container of water on the load cell and drop marbles into the water one after another ... the water cushions the marbles and keeps them from bouncing too much